# Problemas con Primary Key a la hora de exportar una base de datos en SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, express, sql-server-2012

Estoy intentando exportar una base de datos `"pruebabd1"` de un SGBD SQL a otro en otro equipo de forma remota y manteniendo los datos. Consigo que los dos SGBD se conecten el uno a otro con el usuario "sa".

Esquema:

Exportar de PC1 a PC2

```
BD pruebabd1 en PC1<br>
BD pruebabd2 en PC2

pruebabd1 Columnas: ["id_lololo" PK IDENTITY=ON INT],["lololo" NCHAR(9)]<br>
pruebabd2 Columnas: ["id_lololo" PK IDENTITY=ON INT],["lololo" NCHAR(9)]
```

La función de Exportar (al hacer clic derecho sobre la BD, Task, Export) me funciona bien cuando la base de datos de PC2 está vacía (creo una BD con el nombre de pruebabd2 pero la dejo vacía).

El problema viene cuando la pruebabd2 tiene contenido, ya que al estar en IDENTITY=ON (para que la id se rellene sola), algunos de estos números coinciden y da error (porque no pueden haber 2 registros iguales en la/las columna/s de la PK).

En el primer error me pone que la columna está en modo lectura, no entiendo por qué.

Mensajes de error:

> Error 0xc0202049: Tarea Flujo de datos 1: Error de inserción en la columna de sólo lectura "id_lololo".
>        (Asistente para importación y exportación de SQL Server)
>
> Error 0xc0202045: Tarea Flujo de datos 1: Error en la validación de metadatos de columna.
>        (Asistente para importación y exportación de SQL Server)
>
> Error 0xc004706b: Tarea Flujo de datos 1: Error en la validación de "Destino - tabla_prueba". Se devolvió el estado de validación "VS_ISBROKEN".
>        (Asistente para importación y exportación de SQL Server)
>
> Error 0xc004700c: Tarea Flujo de datos 1: Error al validar uno o más componentes.
>        (Asistente para importación y exportación de SQL Server)
>
> Error 0xc0024107: Tarea Flujo de datos 1: Se produjeron errores al validar la tarea.
>        (Asistente para importación y exportación de SQL Server)

[image: error1]

Comment: Sabes inglés? Buscando el primer error que marca el sql server encontré [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948819/error-0xc0202049-data-flow-task-1-failure-inserting-into-the-read-only-column) en el sitio en inglés.